# Custom Validator based on Parent Date

Tags: validation, grails

I have a domain (Travel) with the typical start and end date and the validation works there don't worry. The issue lies in the child domain (Destination) where there can be many Destinations to one Travel and I can't get the custom validation to reject start and end dates outside the bounds of Travel's overall start and end dates. Is there a way to do a custom validation based on a val>Travel.endDate?

```
startDate blank: true, nullable: true, validator: { 
        val, obj -> if (!val) ['startDateEmpty']
        if (val>Travel.startDate) return ['invalidStartTripDate']
    }
endDate blank: true, nullable: true, validator: { 
        val, obj -> if (!val) ['endDateEmpty']
        if (val<obj.startDate) return ['invalidDates']
        if (val>Travel.endDate) return ['invalidEndTripDate']
}
```

I tried the above code but invalidEndTripDate and invalidStartTripDate cause other validations to break down. Destination also belongsTo(Travel). Thanks for any help!

Edit: For those that have asked here are the domains

```
class Travel {

static hasMany = [destinations: TravelDestination]

User user
Integer id
String tripName
Date startDate
Date endDate

static mapping = {
    table 'travel'
    id generator: 'identity'
    version false
}

static constraints = {
    def regEx = new RegEx()

    tripName blank: false, nullable: false, matches: regEx.address //Allows alphanumeric and some special characters
    startDate blank: true, nullable: true, validator: { 
        val, obj -> if (!val) ['startDateEmpty']
    }
    endDate blank: true, nullable: true, validator: { 
        val, obj -> if (!val) ['endDateEmpty']
        if (val<obj.startDate) return ['invalidDates']
    } 
}
```

Second:

```
class TravelDestination {

static belongsTo = [travel: Travel]

Integer id

// Travel Information
Country country
String city
Date startDate
Date endDate

static mapping = {
    table 'destination'
    id generator: 'identity'
    version false
}

static constraints = {
    def regEx = new RegEx()

    country blank: false, nullable: false 
    city blank: false, nullable: false, matches: regEx.name 
    startDate blank: true, nullable: true, validator: { 
        val, obj -> if (!val) ['startDateEmpty']
    }
    endDate blank: true, nullable: true, validator: { 
        val, obj -> if (!val) ['endDateEmpty']
        if (val<obj.startDate) return ['invalidDates']
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming your domain has a property that contains the `Travel` instance it would be `obj.travelPropertyName.endDate`

Comment: I don't have one at the moment. The only reference to Travel was the belongsTo

Comment: show how yours Travel and Destination domain classes looks

Comment: and what is not ok if you are doing what you have in first comment? I mean if you will change "if (val>Travel.startDate)" to "if (val>obj.travel.startDate)". Same with endDate.

Comment: In your validator, `Travel.endDate` is a static access to a n instance property, which obviously will cause errrors. Try to replae it with `obj.travel.endDate`. same for `startDate` validaton.